# How to remove duplicate namespace attributes from nodes in xml?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I have two huge 1 gb xml files.both has same structure.I am trying to merge them.
script use xmltextreader and xmltextwriter.it works fine except it duplicating namespace to multiple nodes. I read so many blogs and documents but couln't find proper solution.
Any idea or help is really appriciated.

For test puspose i am just reading from below xml and writing to new xml file.
In output file tittle node has this extra namespace which i dont want.

Below is my sample xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<records xmnls:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="sample.xsd">
<record category="xyz" editor="" entered="sdsd" sub-category="sds" uid="ds" updated="sd-07-15">
    <person ssn="" e-i="M">
      <title xsi:nil="true"/>
      <position>abcd</position>
      <names>
        <first_name>xyz</first_name>
        <last_name>xyz</last_name>
      </names>
    </person>
</record>
<record category="xyz" editor="" entered="sdsd" sub-category="sds" uid="ds" updated="sd-07-15">
    <person ssn="" e-i="M">
      <title xsi:nil="true"/>
      <position>abcd</position>
      <names>
        <first_name>xyz</first_name>
        <last_name>xyz</last_name>
      </names>
    </person>
</record>
</records>

my code is as below

        Public Sub Main()
        Dim DownloadPEPLocation As String = Dts.Variables("xyz").Value
        Dim ACTIMIZESource As String = Dts.Variables("ACTIMIZESource").Value
        Dim PEPTextReader As Xml.XmlTextReader
        Dim Destination As Xml.XmlTextWriter
        Destination = New Xml.XmlTextWriter(ACTIMIZESource, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        Destination.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        Destination.Namespaces = True

        PEPTextReader = New XmlTextReader(DownloadPEPLocation)
        PEPTextReader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None

        Destination.WriteStartDocument()
        Destination.WriteStartElement("records")

        Destination.WriteAttributeString("xmnls:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
        Destination.WriteAttributeString("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "world-check.xsd")

        Dim PEPreading As Boolean = PEPTextReader.Read()
        Do While (PEPreading)
            If (PEPTextReader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element And PEPTextReader.LocalName = "record") Then
                Destination.WriteNode(PEPTextReader, True)
                Destination.Flush()
            Else
                PEPreading = PEPTextReader.Read()
            End If
        Loop

        Destination.WriteEndElement()
        Destination.WriteEndDocument()
        Destination.Close()
        PEPTextReader.Close()


Output is look like this.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<records xmnls:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="sample.xsd">
<record category="xyz" editor="" entered="sdsd" sub-category="sds" uid="ds" updated="sd-07-15">
    <person ssn="" e-i="M">
      <title xsi:nil="true" **xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"** />
      <position>abcd</position>
      <names>
        <first_name>xyz</first_name>
        <last_name>xyz</last_name>
      </names>
    </person>
</record>
<record category="xyz" editor="" entered="sdsd" sub-category="sds" uid="ds" updated="sd-07-15">
    <person ssn="" e-i="M">
      <title xsi:nil="true" **xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"** />
      <position>abcd</position>
      <names>
        <first_name>xyz</first_name>
        <last_name>xyz</last_name>
      </names>
    </person>
</record>
</records>

`
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tapan: Based on your input and output examples, it appears that two letters have been inadvertantly transposed on the `xmlns` attribute in the `<records>` root element:

```
<records xmnls:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         ^^^^^
```

The attribute reads `xmnls` instead of `xmlns`. Because of this, the `xsi` namespace prefix is not being defined the way you think it is.

Try making this change in the input file to see if the apparently redundant `xsi` attributes in the output file go away.

Comment: thanks for updates. I did changes but still its not working.Any idea how to remove duplicate namespace.